# SQL: What is a value?

Tags: sql, normalization, postgresql-9.2, database-normalization, denormalization

### The Question

One thing that I am confused about is the technical definition of possibly the most basic component of a database: a single value.

### Some Examples

I understand and follow (at a minimum) the first three normal forms of database normalization - or so I think. That said, with the introduction of `RANGE` in PostgreSQL 9.2 I started thinking about what makes a single value.

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html):

> Range types are useful because they represent many element values in a single range value

**So, what are you? Several values, or a single value... nothingness... 42?**

### Why does this matter?

Because is speaks directly to the **Second Normal Form**:

1. Create separate tables for sets of values that apply to multiple records.
2. Relate these tables with a foreign key.

---

### #1 Ranges

For example, in **Postgres 9.1** I had some tables structured like this:

**"SomeSchema"."StatusType"**

```
   "StatusTypeID"   |  "StatusType"
--------------------|----------------
         1          |    Start
         2          |    Stop
```

**"SomeSchema"."Statuses"**

```
   "StatusID"  |  "Identifier"  |  "StatusType"  | "Value" |     "Timestamp"        
---------------|----------------|----------------|---------|---------------------
       1       |        1       |       1        |    0    | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
       2       |        1       |       2        |    5    | 2000-01-02 12:00:00
       3       |        2       |       1        |    1    | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
       4       |        3       |       1        |    2    | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
       5       |        2       |       2        |    7    | 2000-01-01 18:30:00
       6       |        1       |       2        |    3    | 2000-01-02 12:00:00
```

This enabled me to keep an historical record of how things were configured at any given point in time.
This structure takes the position that the data in the "Value" column were all separate values.

Now, in **Postgres 9.2** if I do the same thing with a `RANGE` value it would look like this:

**"SomeSchema"."Statuses"**

```
   "StatusID"  |  "Identifier"  |  "Value"    |     "Timestamp"        
---------------|----------------|-------------|---------------------
       1       |        1       |  (0, NULL)  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
       2       |        1       |  (0, 5)     | 2000-01-02 12:00:00
       3       |        2       |  (1, NULL)  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
       4       |        3       |  (2, NULL)  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
       5       |        2       |  (1, 7)     | 2000-01-01 18:30:00
       6       |        1       |  (0, 3)     | 2000-01-02 12:00:00
```

Again, this structure would enable me to keep an historical record of how things were configured, but I would be storing the same value several times in separate places. It makes updating (technically inserting a new record) more tricky because I have to make sure the data rolls over from the original record.

### #2 Arrays

Arrays have been around for a long time, and while they can be abused, I tend to use them for things like color codes. For example, my project stores information and at times needs to know how to display it. I could create three columns to store `red`, `green`, and `blue` values; but that just seems silly. When would I ever create a foreign key (or even just filter) based on one of the given color codes.

When I created the field it was from the perspective that I needed to store a color in a neutral format so that I could feed anything that accepts a color value. I made the column an array and filled it with the appropriate codes to make the color I want.

### #3 PostGIS: Geometry & Geography

When storing a polygon in PostGIS, it stores all the points that make the boundary in a single field. If one point were to change and I wanted to keep an historical record, I would have to store all of the points that have not changed twice in order to store the new polygon along with the old.

---

So, what is a value? and... if `RANGE`, `ARRAY`, and `GEOGRAPHY` are values do they really break the second normal form?

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand your first example, or what the problem with that is. But if an array would be bad (as in, breaking normalisation rules), consider the good old string. If i store two strings "OneString" and "TwoString", would you be concerned about breaking NF2 because you store the characters 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g' redundantly? I think not, since you are, as with your colors, not regarding a single character as a value, but rather the whole set of characters that form the string. So, the _values_ are different, and i see no breaking of NF2.

Comment: I like your example of the string; however, an argument could be made by the purest that strings are in fact redundant and should have limited use.

Comment: It isn't necessary to deconstruct a value into ever smaller parts just because it can be. The eventual conclusion would presumably be everything represented only as individual bits. To what end? The value of higher level languages and data models is precisely that they provide high levels of abstraction - a rich and powerful set of types and operators that humans find convenient to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that some operation can derive new values from X that appear to be components of X's value doesn't mean X itself isn't "single valued". Thus "range" values and "geography" values should be single values as far as the DBMSs type system is concerned. I don't know enough about Postgresql's implementation to know whether "arrays" can be considered as single values in themselves. SQL DBMSs like Postgresql are not truly *relational* DBMSs and SQL supports various structures that certainly aren't proper relation variables, values or types (pointers, nulls and other exotica).

This is a difficult and sometimes controversial topic however. If you haven't read it then I recommend the book ***Databases, Types, and the Relational Model - The Third Manifesto*** by Date and Darwen. It addresses exactly the kind of questions you are asking about.

I don't like your description of 2NF but it's not very relevant here.

Comment: What description of 2NF do you like? I found the one I posted at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878 and thought it did a fair job of communicating the concept.

Comment: "A relation R is in second normal form if it is in first normal form and every non-prime attribute of R is fully dependent on each candidate key of R." - E.F.Codd